# Where can I get SQL Server Native Client for Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-native-client

I wanted to build the open source project [sqlines](https://github.com/dmtolpeko/sqlines) in linux which can migrate rds data to another

The project dep serveral db connector, include sql-server connector.

I had spent long time to look up "SQL Server Native Client", but I can only find the connector for windows system.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft library for SQL Server connectivity from native code on Linux is the [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).  "SQL Server Native Client" is the name of an old driver package for Windows, which has subsequently been replaced by the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server (multi-platform) and the [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) (Windows-only).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try the ODBC Driver